# How to display membership info and profile on Gridview in ASP.net

Tags: gridview, asp.net-membership, asp.net-profiles

I can display information of user profile in Gridview, but I can not display Email of users.
plaese you see below my code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridUser" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
    GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="UserName" />
        <%--<asp:BoundField DataField="EMail" HeaderText="E-Mail Address" />--%>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And in code-behind:

```
List<object> profileList = new List<object>();
MembershipUserCollection muc = Membership.GetAllUsers();
foreach (MembershipUser mu in muc)
{
    profileList.Add(Profile.GetProfile(mu.UserName));         
}
GridUser.DataSource = profileList;
GridUser.DataBind();
```

Now, How I can display Email of users plus profile of users in Gridview?

Answer (score 0):

Create you own entity that inherits from MembershipUser and extend it by adding properties that will hold profile informations. Populate your new entity and then bind it to GridView. This is the cleanest way to do.